# Codeigniter encryption class producing inconsistent results

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

I am testing out the codeigniter encrypt library and can not seem to get consistent results. 
I set up a test page which basically just has the following code

```
    $pwd = "test string";
    $key = "testkey_obviously_it_will_be_more_secure";
    for ($i=0; $i<11; $i++){
        echo $this->encrypt->encode($pwd, $key)."<br>";
    }
```

The output is 10 completely different lines of characters.

I am obviously doing something wrong but I can't see what it could be. I have tried using the encode function with and without a $key but the results are the same for me.

By the way, I am using codeigniter 2.1.0 in my test environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding library works as expected. Let's have a look at the default mcrypt_encode() method:

```
function mcrypt_encode($data, $key)
{
        $init_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_get_cipher(), $this->_get_mode());
        $init_vect = mcrypt_create_iv($init_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return $this->_add_cipher_noise($init_vect.mcrypt_encrypt($this->_get_cipher(), $key, $data, $this->_get_mode(), $init_vect), $key);
}
```

Notice the random factor that takes place inside encoding and that noise is added to the encryption. Try storing the 10 keys that you're generating into an array and decrypting them. You'll get your values back correctly.

If you're looking for encoding strictly one-way and producing consistent results, I suggest using the hash() method in PHP (available since 5.1.2 onwards): http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.hash.php

A safe way of generating hashes is to create a random *seed* value, and then concatenate that to the user's password. This defends you against rainbow table cracking and other things.

```
hash('sha512', $seed . $password);
```

**Update:** The idea is that the encryption class is used in order to be able to encode and **also decode** some strings. Think of it this way - it's not a secure example, but it will do for understanding the point: You want to store a person's credit card information on your website. You want to keep this information secure, of course, so that if somebody breaks into your database, it's not a huge deal, since all of that info is encrypted. You of course also want to be able to decode that information and display it to the user in case they order something from your website again, rather than having them input the data by hand, so you also need to be able to decrypt that data.

Generally, as a rule of thumb, it is my understanding that if an encryption algorithm is two-way (that is, it can be encoded and decoded), then it is not as secure as a one-way encryption algorithm (that only encodes data).

If you're storing user login credentials, you'll never want to be able to decode a user's password for example, since that's something that a user can easily reset. You never want to display a user's password on an account, so you always keep it firmly locked. This is where you use a one-way encryption algorithm - you encode the data once, when you create the entry, and then when you're looking for an entry in your DB, instead of running something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE user.password = 'STAR_WARS'
```

You would run something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE user.password = '5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e'
```

The above can be achieved by encoding the data that you're receiving from the user the first time, when you're setting up their account, and then whenever you're checking login credentials, you just run the encoding algorithm on the string they provide.

As a workflow for creating a new account:

1. User creates a new account with password 'starwars'.
2. User is saved in DB with password '5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e', which is obtained by running md5() on the password the user has provided.

Workflow for authenticating a user:

1. User sends password 'starwars' through login form.
2. Password is encoded into '5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e'.
3. We check our database entries for where the password is '5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e'.

In the system above, we never store the user's original password - only the encrypted data.

Now that seems simple in itself, but MD5 as an encryption algorithm has been fully cracked - that is, because there are only so many combinations of strings possible, most of the values have been reversed, so hackers take the value '5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e' and they run it through a script that lists out possible login passwords which all map to '5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e', amongst which we will also find 'starwars'.

The important thing is to make your password generation not as long or obfuscated as possible, but as random as possible. That's why in the example above, we generate a **seed** which we use to add a random element to a password, and we use stronger encryption algorithms.

So a seed might be the string: 'sajuh27ahjs'.

When a user creates a new account, we concatenate the seed with their original password. So for our star wars example, the user's original password before being encrypted would be:

```
'sajuh27ahjsstarwars'
```

The seed is stored in the database, without encryption, in plain sight, as we will need it later to decode. Okay, so now we encrypt the password with something strong, like SHA512. Thus we obtain:

```
hash('sha512', $seed . $password);
```

Notice how this attack is very difficult to break, because the seed adds a random element, which makes it hard for the breaker to understand where we've placed the seed, and even with that knowledge, it requires building a table of values mapping for every particular random seed that can be generated (which is a lot).

Hope that clears up some things, feel free to shoot more questions otherwise!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still a little confused, but I did as you suggested and placed the 10 values into an array and was rewarded with the original string 10 times. I guess this method is not suitable for storing passwords into a database as the comparison for equality would fail every time. I will look into the hash method and see if I can make sense of that. Thanks again!

Comment: @o11y_75 Hey man, I've updated my answer with some more info. Thanks for letting me know that there were some bits you didn't understand - I hope that the update explains some more about the process!